# Need to change the value of SharePoint list using jslink

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom, jslink

I want to change the value of one of my column in SharePoint list with the help of jslink. For that I have done

[image]

and linked this file with webpart using

[image]

but for me, the function "ViewTemplate(ctx)" is not firing. Can anybody suggest a solution for my problem.

Comment: Double check if your JS is loading properly...May be Place an alert/console log at the top in your JS file to verify the same.

Answer (score 2):

May be MDS is enabled on your SharePoint site. In this case you will need to use **RegisterModuleInit()** function.

You need to do two modifications to achieve this.

First, you need to change the anonymous entry point function to a function with an entry point signature.  Then, you need to call **RegisterModuleInit()** function to register an override of this code on MDS enabled sites.

**For example:**

```
RegisterModuleInit("CSRAssets/CSRFieldType.js", RegisterFavoriteColor); // CSR-override for MDS enabled site
RegisterFavoriteColor(); //CSR-override for MDS disabled site (because we need to call the entry point function in this case whereas it is not needed for anonymous functions)

function RegisterFavoriteColor() {
    var favoriteColorContext = {};

    // You can provide templates for:
    // View, DisplayForm, EditForm and NewForm
    favoriteColorContext.Templates = {};
    favoriteColorContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "FavoriteColorField": {
            "View": favoriteColorViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        favoriteColorContext
        );
}

// The favoriteColorViewTemplate provides the rendering logic
//  the custom field type when it is displayed in the view form.
function favoriteColorViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var color = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return "<span style='background-color : " + color +
        "' >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;" + color;
}
```

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an alert in the beginning of the ViewTemplates function. I have shared the implementation that assigns values to Column C by comparing the values for Column A & Column B using CSR and JSLink.

```
function TargetProgress(ctx) {
var totalSalesVal =ctx.CurrentItem.Total_x0020_Sales.replace(",", "");
var targetSalesVal =ctx.CurrentItem.Sales_x0020_Target.replace(",", "");

  if(parseInt(totalSalesVal) > parseInt(targetSalesVal))
  {
     return "On Target";
  }
  else if(parseInt(targetSalesVal)- parseInt(totalSalesVal) <=1000 )
  {
     return "Reaching Target";
  }
  else
 {
     return "Long way to target !";
  }
}
```

[image: Assign Column Values]

Comment: Please add more details from your link and add the link as a reference to avoid the broken links in the future, thanks!